# Fully disable node auto-offset

Tags: node-editor, interface, customization

The node editor's auto-offset feature can be disabled under the View menu. However, any time you open a new node editor window, it will be enabled by default in that window. I am looking for a way to have it be disabled by default when creating new node editor windows. Is this possible? There are options to control the amount of offset in Preferences -> Editing -> Miscellaneous. But not to disable it completely.

Comment: Hi :). Setting it to 0 pixels effectively disables it. Why doesn't that work for you? :)

Comment: Also opening a new node editor keeps the Auto-Offset disabled in Blender 3.1 :))

Comment: @JachymMichal The offset amount is how much space is made between nodes when it offsets. 0 means no space, but it will still position them side to side, so that doesn't work. And I am using 3.1 and this still happens :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a new option for this at `Preferences -> Editing -> Node Editor` in Blender v4.0.  It's a global option now, meaning we don't have to set it for each Node Editor.

<sub>(Note: the option was removed from the `View` menu.)</sub>